# Can I convert an Iterator<Item=io::Result<u8>> to io::Result<Vec<u8>> without panicking?

Tags: iterator, rust, panic

I have an `Iterator<Item=io::Result<u8>>` that I'd like to convert to `io::Result<Vec<u8>>`.

```
iter.map(|x| x.unwrap()).collect::<Vec<u8>>()
```

will give me the `Vec<u8>` but how can I keep the `Err` part in case of an error?

Answer (score 0):

@aspex thanks for you help, it's

```
let fold: io::Result<Vec<_>> = iter.collect();
```